# How to define 'guild'?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I need guild defined 'guild' I am getting the following error

> Error: (node:8576) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: guild is not defined

js

```
 if(msg.content.startsWith (prefix + 'mp')) {
    var text = msg.content.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ')
    if(!text) return msg.reply('Veuillez spécifié votre message !')
    msg.guild.send(text)
  }
```

Comment: mplungjan x) Help me,

Answer (score 0):

You can't send a message to a Guild, you can *however* send a message to a Guild Channel. So instead of having `msg.guild.send(text)` you can use either

```
// Send a message to the channel where the user entered the command
msg.channel.send(text);
```

or use

```
// Send a message to a specific Guild Channel
let channel = msg.guild.channels.find((channel) => channel.name === '<channel name here>');
channel.send(text);
```